# Set Element active and the other inactive (dynamic)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a listbox

```
<div id="listboxid1" class="listboxFilters">
  <div class="listboxFilterItem"> <div style="padding-top:2px; float: left;">test2</div>     <div class="listboxChosenFilter">3</div>   </div>
  <div class="listboxFilterItem"> <div style="padding-top:2px; float: left;">test</div>     <div class="listboxChosenFilter">*</div>   </div>
  <div class="listboxFilterItem"> <div style="padding-top:2px; float: left;">gro</div>     <div class="listboxChosenFilter">2</div>   </div>
</div>
```

its a normal listbox, the question is now , how can I only set one element to active , and the others then to inactive

my first guess was an onlick on an item, I add a classname named active and before  I would do a foreach for the listboxid1 element and set all to inactive, but is this really the common and best way?? :

```
 <script>

  function clearAll(element) {

    element.each(function () {
      var checkboxes = $(this).children("div");

      checkboxes.each(function () {
        var checkbox = $(this);
        checkbox.removeClass("active");
      });

    });

  }

  jQuery.fn.multiselecter = function () {
    $(this).each(function () {
      var checkboxes = $(this).children("div");
      checkboxes.each(function () {
        var checkbox = $(this);

        checkbox.click(function () {

          clearAll(checkbox.parent());
          checkbox.addClass("active");

        });

      });
    });
  };
  $("#listbox1").multiselecter();




</script>
```

Comment: You should select all your element with $('.listboxFilterItem') if you are using jQuery and use removeClass method.

$('.listboxFilterItem').removeClass('active');

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using jQuery, so try this functions:

On click on anyitem with class `.listboxFilterItem` call `setActive` function

```
$('.listboxFilterItem').click(setActive($(this)));

function setActive(var elem){
    $('.listboxFilterItem').each(function(){
       $(this).removeClass('active'); 
    });
    elem.addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: I can't imagine a case where you need a class inactive and a class active. Just remove active class should be better.

Comment: you don't need to call `each()` for adding class. just call `addClass` stright for element selection

Comment: but iif i want more Listboxes in one view, i had do declare new  javascript code

Comment: you mean ListBoxes with listboxFilterItems?

Comment: If I have 2 Listboxes with the id  "listboxFilterItem" the JS function wouldn't work i had do declare a new function with new ID parameter of the other

Comment: you cannot have to identical IDs and you can go with classes like this `.parent .listboxFilterItem`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".listboxFilterItem").click(function (e) {
    $(".listboxFilterItem").removeClass("active");
    // or $(".active").removeClass("active");

    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Check this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjm3ehbg/)

Comment: this wont work for more than one Listbox in a view, i used because of this a ID on the listbox

Comment: when have more than one Listbox what you want?

Answer (score 0):

$(this) - element, which was clicked
$(this).siblings() - all his neighbours, except himself.

```
$(".listboxFilterItem").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```